# Getting webpage source code in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am trying to get the source code from a webpage in silverlight.

this is my code

```
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(WebClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://ip-whois-lookup.com/lookup.php?ip=19.118.245.124"));


    void WebClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            Mytext.Text = e.Result.ToString();
        }
        else
            Mytext.Text = e.Error.ToString();
    }
```

and this is my error.

```
System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndGetResponse>b__9(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
```

the same principle for the same url works in a c# console aplication

```
 string htmlContent = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://ip-whois-lookup.com/lookup.php?ip=19.118.245.124");
```

What i'm looking for is to be able to change the ip in that url with any ip of my choosing and get the source code of that page.

The same code that gives the error in silverlight works for other websites: ex: http://tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address/79.118.20.240 , http://livescore.com , but also doesn't for google.com and maybe others.

Comment: `SecurityException`.. seems to me like this is not allowed within a Silverlight application (running in a browser). Have you researched that possibility?

Comment: however, I don't understand why the same code works for some websites but not for others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works because that sites (tcputils.com, livescore.com) has crossdomain.xml file in a root (for example, http://livescore.com/crossdomain.xml). This file is basically an opt-in to allow access to site data from outside site web domain.

If the file is missing (for example, on site http://ip-whois-lookup.com/), request from silverlight app doesn't work. It's silverlight security restriction.

Comment: I was starting to suspect this. Thank you for your response. I'm getting more and more demoralized about the whole silverlight thing. First I coudn't use ping &co beacause they are not supported by SL and had to go with wcf, now this.